# understanding method call in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am going through some code like the following:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // Write the response message, in an HTML page
    try {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");  // HTML 5
        out.println("<html><head>");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");

        out.println(Add_To_Test()); 

        out.println("<head><title>Test API</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h3>My message</h3>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
```

I have `Add_To_Test` method defined as follows:

```
public static Object Add_To_Test() throws IOException {
// Some code here
}
```

1) My questions is, is `out.println(Add_To_Test());` a correct way of calling the method and displaying its contents?

2) What is the meaning of adding `public static Object` before the method name?

Comment: maybe Servlets are not the best place to start learning Java programming, I suggest you trying simpler stuff

Comment: @sleiman Jneidi I am just trying to understand what's going on there if you can explain?

Comment: You are asking several questions here that can better be answered by reading an introductory Java tutorial.

Comment: Never mind. Someone answered what I was looking for. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it is legal. Yes, it will send the return value of the `toString` method of the `Object`, returned from the `Add_To_Test` method, to the `OutputStream` of the `Response` Object. (`println` should call `toString` method implicitly) And it will be displayed in the terminal or browser, depending on what you use for the connection to the servlet.

2) **public** -> means this can be accessed by any object from any package of your program.

**static** -> means this is the class method, which can be called directly without instantiating the class first.

**Object** -> Java basic class, from which all other classes you ever write or use, inherit.